# Is there anyway to bypass the 14 GB update in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

After activating the GTA V by putting serial code, it asks for a 14GB+ patch file download. This is really frustrating that the download looks very huge. Now my questions are:

1. Is there anyway to bypass the 14GB download?
2. What problem do I face if I did so?

Comment: @TimmyJim Yes PC. Cancel is different from complete bypassing

Comment: @TimmyJim So to play GTA online, this update is necessary.

Comment: You need to be up to date to play online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you need the update. I believe you even need them to play single player, despite none of the updates being single-player related.

I assume you recently purchased (or at least installed) a hard-copy of the game. It's unfortunate, but when purchasing a game that's over 2 years old, and one that's still being frequently updated, you will need to get new content.

To the best of my knowledge, they (game companies in general) never re-release the disks to include newer content, unless they re-release the game as a separate edition (think game of the year edition, ultimate edition etc).

---

You could *bypass* the update if you have a local friend who has all the updates, and simply copying the game from their computer (in Steam, you could use Backup and Restore game, but even without Steam you can simply copy their installation files to your computer)